# Varnishlog truncating user agent

Tags: varnish

I'm using the following `varnishlog` command (the version is `varnish-5.2.1 revision 67e562482`, and I'm running on Ubuntu `18.04.3`) to list any ReqHeader:

```sh
varnishlog -i ReqHeader -c
```

The User-Agent header looks like this:

```
-   ReqHeader      User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; Media Center PC 5.0; SLCC1; OfficeLiveConnector.1.5; OfficeLivePatch.1.3; .NET4.0C; Lunasc
```

I'm finding that, for some devices (for example, the above one), the line is truncated. It's not clear whether the truncation is imposed on the whole line, on the value for the header, or the length of the user agent string, but regardless, there's truncation at some point:

- The full line is limited to 273 characters
- The text starting from `User-Agent` is limited to 254 characters
- The user agent itself is limited to 242 characters

How can I increase the truncation limit so that a longer user agent can be displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Varnish 5.2, which is end-of-life, [the documentation says that the maximum VSL record length is set to 255 bytes.](http://varnish-cache.org/docs/5.2/reference/varnishd.html#vsl-reclen) .This is configurable via the `vcl_reclen` runtime parameter.

Let's say you want to set this to *4084 bytes*. You can do this by adding the following runtime parameter to `varnishd`:

```
-p vsl_reclen=4084
```

You can always verify this value by running the following command:

```sh
$ varnishadm param.show vsl_reclen
vsl_reclen
        Value is: 4084b [bytes] (default)
        Minimum is: 16b
        Maximum is: 4084

        Maximum number of bytes in SHM log record.
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! Just tested this and can confirm it works flawlessly!